vuejs nuxt js + Laravel with multi tenants
I have a multi-customer online store project
The issue of multiple domains has been solved in Laravel with multi tenant
But in the frontend and vuejs nuxt js project
Do you have solutions to implement the idea of ​​multiple domains in Vuejs Nuxt JS?
example.com
In backend = Laravel with multi tenants
Client_1.example.com/api/products
Client_2.example.com/api/products
If front end = vuejs nuxt js
Client_1.example.com
Client_2.example.com

